# General question about time series forecasting

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series

I have a general question about time series forecasting in machine learning. It's not about coding yet, and I'm just trying to understand how I should build the model.

Below is some code I have related to my model:

```
def build_model(my_learning_rate, feature_layer):
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(feature_layer)
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation="relu"))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))  
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=my_learning_rate), loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
  return model
```

Here is my feature layer:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3000, 31), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

The time series forecasting modeling technique I learned recently is totally different than how I have been building the model. The technique involves time windows that use past values (my labels!) as features and the next value as the label. It also involves RNN and LSTM.

Is the way I built the model and the time series forecasting technique fundamentally different and will generate different outcomes? Is the way I have been modeling this reasonable, or I should switch to the proper time series forecasting approach?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to predict from what? For example, are you trying to predict the labels of the time series that you have (time series annotation)? Or are you trying to predict the labels at future time points (forecasting)? In the latter case, do you have temperate data available for future time points when making predictions (nowcasting) or not?

Comment: What are possible values of the label? Is it discrete or continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Using LSTM and Recurrent layers are usually used for time series as the data from previous timestamps are essential to create a successful model to create accurate and precise predictions. For example, when I make models for time series models, I usually use time distributed 1 dimensional convolutional layers. Code below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'),input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1))
```

If you want to implement this yourself, you must reshape the original X array int o n_steps (timestamps) and n_features(number of features in data)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes,if you add the temperature value to each array of data.

Comment: If this answer is what you are looking for, please remember to accept it.

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: When dealing with Time Series data, time is the x axis of the graph of  data. By adding the time-distributed wrapper, the dimension of index one will be considered to be the temporal dimension (i.e The dimension of time).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.